# How to validate if user has selected file to upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

I need to make a form validation using `JavaScript/jQuery`. My form has one input field where users can upload files and one table where `<td>` are input fields. Like this:

```
 <input type="file" name="file" class="filestyle" id="fajl" data-icon="false" accept=".pdf,.csv,.xlsx">
```

And this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
<tbody>
<tr id="prvi_red">
<td><input type="text" name="user1_name" class="form-control" placeholder="12121212" required></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user1_surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Text" required></td>
<td><input type="text" name="user1_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Number" required></td>
</tr>
```

And also I have one button which submits whole form(both uploaded files and manually inserted in table). I tried to validate form like this, using `Parsley.js` validation plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1').submit(function(){
        if(($('#fajl').val()=='')){
            console.log('ovdje sam');
            var validateForm = $('#prvi_red').parsley().validate();
            if(validateForm){
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buton').click(function(){//when submit button is clicked
        if(($('#fajl').val()=='')){
            console.log('ovdje sam');
            var validateForm = $('#prvi_red').parsley().validate();
            if(validateForm){
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, what I'm trying to achieve is to make validation of table input fields if file is not uploaded. But in both cases od above code nothing happens. I tried to put `console.log('ovdje sam');` just to test if script comes to that part, but that is not displayed in console neither. Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: try `var file = $('#fajl')[0].files;
   if(file.length > 0)` to validate if the input is empty

Comment: Didn't help. It doesn't show anything in console.

Comment: did you put any file in the input type file?

Comment: No, i did not. I'm trying to make validation of input fields if input with `type='file'` is empty. Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: what i have there is if the input is not empty like this `var file = $('#fajl')[0].files; if(file.length > 0) {alert('not empty')}else{alert('empty')}`

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to remove the attribute `required` when the user specifies a file. Listen to the `input` event on your file input and update the other inputs accordingly. When they are updated, you should trigger `'input'` (or call `parsley().validate()`) so any error message displayed is removed.